# Очень медленный mysql запрос из за ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, order-by

Есть таблица с комментариями (более 5миллионов записей)

```
CREATE TABLE `topic_comment` (
    `topic_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `comment_text` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `comment_timestamp` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment_activity` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `rate_pl` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `rate_mi` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `topic_id` (`topic_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `comment_activity` (`comment_activity`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `comment_timestamp` (`comment_timestamp`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=5528579;
```

Таблица пользователей (это не столь важно)

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_email` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `user_email` (`user_email`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=216013;
```

Есть запрос который из за ORDER BY очень медленный!

```
SELECT  tc.*, u.user_email
FROM topic_comment tc 
left JOIN user u ON u.user_id = tc.user_id 
WHERE tc.topic_id = '45712' 
ORDER BY tc.comment_id  
LIMIT 6, 15
```

Вот как проверяю время выполнения

```
$prevTime = microtime(true);
после запроса
$curTime = microtime(true);
ECHO $diffTime = round($curTime - $prevTime, 2);
```

А вот результат на достаточно не плохом железе 11.67!

Если убрать сортировку запрос срабатывает очень быстро, но, к сожалению, последовательность нарушена!

Буду признателен за совет!

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос EXPLAIN своего запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Если ориентироваться на смысл, то

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM topic_comment tc 
       WHERE tc.topic_id = '45712' 
       ORDER BY tc.comment_id  
       LIMIT 6, 15 ) subq
JOIN user u ON u.user_id = subq.user_id
```

Но отсутствие схемы и отсутствие внешних ключей в показанной структуре допускает любой [censored] - так что проверяй, соответствует ли это требуемой логике.

---

Дополнительно.

1. Прибить индекс по topic_id, а вместо него создать композитный по `(topic_id, comment_id)`
2. Хорошенько подумать, нужны ли ВСЕ поля. Заменить звёзды на список реально необходимых полей.
3. В соответствии с п. 2 пересмотреть индекс, создаваемый по п. 1.

Comment: 1 помогло. спасибо.